# I need a htaccess RewriteRule for a simple pattern

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want something like the following:

```
http://fref.co/anystring
```

to be rewritten as:

```
http://fref.co/?q=anystring
```

This is how far I've gone:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I found the problem. I didn't realize the RewriteRule could be applied on the Rewritten url. So, /anystring would go to /index.php?q=anystring and then that would go to /index.php?q=index.php?q=anystring. Weird. I replace the . in the RewriteRule with [a-z0-9_-] and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your needs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Internally redirect http://fref.co/anystring to http://fref.co/?q=anystring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]

# Redirect http://fref.co/?q=anystring to http://fref.co/anystring
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(/index\.php|/)\?q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What do the following do:
    `+FollowSymLinks`,
    `-MultiViews`,
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`,
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` ?

Comment: @user2593666 [you can read about the **Options here**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) as for the conditions they are to verify if the file or directory exist or not before internally redirecting it.